# What is the SystemResourceNotifyWindow?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, winforms, winapi

In the Windows OS or API, there is apparently something known as the "SystemResourceNotifyWindow", referenced in these two places on the internet: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/41e0bf65-2e96-4d0f-98aa-2c0cf31aa493) and [here](http://northhorizon.net/2010/how-to-actually-change-the-system-theme-in-wpf/). And in .NET code [here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/NetFXw7/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/SystemResources@cs/5/SystemResources@cs).

However, I can't seem to find any useful information about it. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code, this is a WPF-specific window that is used to listen for changes to the windows theme and notify the presentationcore when this occurs.

Comment: Yes, that could be a part of the answer based on the code. I was hoping for something a little more authoritative.

Comment: Sorry, I doubt that there is going to be anything more authoritative than the source code since this appears to be an internal, undocumented piece of functionality.

Comment: Ok, well I think you're probably right that it's simply an internal .NET artifact and isn't at the Win32 level. Thanks for giving it your take.

Comment: It looks to me like only the name (`SystemResourceNotifyWindow`) is WPF-specific. This looks like a regular [message-only window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only).

Comment: I found your question when looking for a fix for dexpot. I use dexpot to force Visual Studios on to a specific desktop with mutliple monitors (this program hides and shows windows based on some other logic). Anyway, the program isn't 100% accurate and sometimes reveals hidden windows. Visual studios sometimes has another window with this title. It's near impossible to get rid of once it appears.